# VB.net: Why I can NOT get the return value from my own stored procedure?

Tags: .net, vb.net, stored-procedures, return-value

Why I can NOT get the return value (Scope_Identity) by executing my own Stored procedure (SQL Server 2008) via this below code written in VB.NET 2008? The SP inserts the new record into Table1 but I have 0 as the return value!

What's wrong with it?

here is my vb.net code and my SP:

```
Public Function Insert(ByVal Obj As entity, connectionString As String) As Integer
    Dim ScopeIdentity As Integer
    Dim Connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using Command As New SqlCommand
        With Command
            .Connection = Connection 
            .CommandTimeout = 300
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "S_Test"
            If .Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                .Connection.Open()
            End If
            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(Command)
            With .Parameters
                 .Item("@Name").Value = Obj.Name
                .Item("@Age").Value = Obj.Age
            End With
            Dim ScopeIdentityParameter As New SqlParameter("ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int)
            ScopeIdentityParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
            Command.Parameters.Add(ScopeIdentityParameter)
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ScopeIdentity = System.Convert.ToInt32(ScopeIdentityParameter.Value)
        End With
    End Using
    Return ScopeIdentity
End Function
```

my own simple Stored Procedure body:

```
 insert into dbo.Table1(Name, Age) values(@Name, @Age)
 return SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 2):

Either change your VB code to take an interest in the return value (eg: `Command.ExecuteScalar()` rather than `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` at the end of the proc) or change your stored procedure to set the OUT param eg: `set @ReturnValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `return SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Your VB code currently expects the proc to set an output parameter but `return SCOPE_IDENTITY()` doesn't set the parameter.

See here for context on SCOPE_IDENTITY() as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: "but return SCOPE_IDENTITY() doesn't set the parameter." Well, Thank you for your notaton. I know about OUT Parameters but It's the first time I use Return value in SP. How can I take advantage of using return (like return SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AND get its value within vb.net ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question when I wrote my answer. I don't know why your return value isn't getting from the proc to the code. I suspect it's something to do with the default return value of 0 being applied and your implicit return being ignored. Is the insert to Table1 working? if not the return value is being set to the number of affected rows, rather than the scope identity.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a mistake in your code instead of the existing line

```
ScopeIdentity = System.Convert.ToInt32(ScopeIdentityParameter.Value)
```

You should use:

```
ScopeIdentity = System.Convert.ToInt32(ReturnValue.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I just had the same problem and it seems I figured out the correct answer.

It has to do with SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters.

DeriveParameters automatically adds the returnValue pararameter and gives it the name "@RETURN_VALUE", so just refer to that and you will get its value.

You can also skip DeriveParameters and add all parameters yourself, for example with AddWithValue or similar, including your ReturnValue-parameter (with any name you like).

But both executing DeriveParameters and adding the ReturnValue-parameter yourself will not work.